# Image resizing not working properly in IOS 7

Tags: ios6, ios7, uiimage, cgcontext

Just curious to know why my simple image resizing code not working properly for 2 different pngs of same image. I am getting these image from 2 different masked frame. One giving blank other working fine.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320, 320));
        [maskedImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
        UIImage*  imageThumb2 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yem8e0nbu0pmz4x/MaskedImage1.png
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wefvbnrgu9bg90z/MaskedImage1%202.png

Answer (score 0):

Always use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.f)`